# Why is Quadro often compared to CPU?

Tags: nvidia-quadro

I find a lot of benchmarks that compare Quadro and CPU performance in same graphs.

Is it rellevant comparison? Ie. the same program will run x-times faster on Quadro, then on regular multi-core CPU? Assuming, that program is made for many-core parallelization of CPU.

IMHO, Quadro is like Geforce. The power comes from SIMD proccessing data in parallel, but using same operations - process many vertices/vectors in parallel. However, when it comes to "random" processing - ie. each core is working with data, that cannot benefit from SIMD vector processing, then it's GPU/Quadro not fully utilized - benchmark graphs are irrelevant.

Comment: CPUs also do SIMD. Most scientific workloads are well-suited for SIMD, too. As such, comparing CPU performance with GPGPU performance is very much valid.